# Rename Pandas Multiindex based on another column's name

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've got a CSV file that is generated in a format I cannot change. The file has a multiindex: headers on two lines. The first line (higher level of index) has blanks when the value doesn't change.

What my header looks like:

[image: Header loos like this]

What it actually comes down to and what I want:

[image: What the header actually is]

I would like to be able to process it correctly in Python 2.7 with Pandas.

I resulted to looping on the first level of index and if the value is blank, set it to be the same as the one on the left.

I start by loading the dataframe in pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myFile, header=[0,1], sep=',')
df
```

[image: Dataframe loaded in Pandas]

I've tried the following:

```
for i, val in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    if val[0][:7] == 'Unnamed':
        l.append([l[i-1][0], val[1]])
    else:
        l.append(val)
```

The list "l" I'm getting appears to be what I want:

```
[('Foo', 'A'),
 ['Foo', 'B'],
 ['Foo', 'C'],
 ('Bar', 'A'),
 ['Bar', 'B'],
 ['Bar', 'C']]
```

I've tried both:

```
df.columns = l
```

Produces a non multiindex dataframe

[image: Flat dataframe]

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(l)
df.reindex(columns = index)
```

This one gives me the correct index, but values disappear.

[image: Disappeared values]

I'm getting a strong gut feeling that the entire approach I'm trying isn't very pythonic nor does it make sense to use a list then converted to a dict. Any idea how I can multiindex properly?

Comment: Your list l seem like a list of tuple AND list, so using MultiIndex,from_tuples() could maybe not work with the list inside l. Try map(tuple, l), before calling index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(l)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `reindex`, set the columns to your new index directly:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(l)
```

That should produce the desired result.

`reindex` doesn't just replace the index values (though that sounds like what it should do, and the documentation isn't especially clear).  Instead it goes through your new indices, picks the rows or columns that match the new indices, and puts `NaN` where no old index matches a new index.  That's what's happening to you: when `reindex` hits `['Foo', 'B']`, which doesn't exist in your original dataframe, it fills the column in the new dataframe with `NaN`.

If your columns are always going to follow a consistent pattern (one top-level column for every three second-level columns, for example), you could also use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) to make the column index:

```
iterables = [["Foo", "Bar"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)
```

Comment: So close and yet I couldn't see this, thanks, it works! Any insight as to whether there's a more efficient/pythonic way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Glad to help!  Better ways to create the column index depend on how your columns are going to vary.  But if they're always going to look roughly like your example, you can use `MultiIndex.from_product()`, which I've added to the answer.

Comment: `MultiIndex.from_product()` just made my life a lot easier ! Thanks a lot !